# How can make multiple stages for running multiple movie files using openGL?

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, bufferedimage, cgcontextdrawimage

I want to make program in xcode on mac where i want to make a window in two stages and two movie will run on it and these movie file data will come from buffer.Thats mean i have two movie file and i want to play these file concurrently in one window on two stages.  How might I do this with OpenGL?

Note That: this movie time interval may be different and different movie file format but all of these movie will come from the buffer to represent in different stage in one window using openGL.

Comment: If you can draw two textures on screen, you just need to create one texture per movie and update each one (with `glTexImage2d`) at the movie rate, and redraw everything when a texture is updated.

Comment: @Ivella thank you very much for your help..can you give me any help or source code..because i have understood your point but i can not make how to draw two texture on screen..if i can do that then i will able to do more...

Comment: I am afraid there is no quick and dirty way of doing this without actually learning OpenGL: there is too much boilerplate code and too many choices you must make to say "just do something like this". Drawing a texture inside a rectangle is one of the most basic OpenGL operations, and I suggest you to follow some tutorial until you are able to do it.

Comment: Anyway thank you..if you give me any help of tutorial than it will helpful for me..